# How to check for availability of a specific network type in android?

Tags: java, android, connectivity, wifi

I wrote an android app, which requires large amount of data to be transfered via the network. To keep the invoices low, I added a switch in my config, which should switch the app to "wlan only" mode.

Unluckily I was unable to implement the correct check for a WLAN connection in my app, the basic idea was adding the needed permissions via

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in my manifest (which should suffice for this purpose) and implemented a simple method which is accessed in my activity:

```
protected boolean checkForNetwork(Context context, boolean wlanOnly) {
    // check via ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!wlanOnly) {
        return manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    } else {
        // hmm... 
    }
}
```

I'm pretty unsure what goes into the // hmm... part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
    return info.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();

You can have a look here ;-)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

> public static class WifiConfiguration.
>   Status int    CURRENT this is the network we are currently connected to